# Tensorflow 2 Semantic Segmentation - loss function for two classes

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, python-3.x, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to implement a U-net for semantic segmentation with two classes (foreground=1 and background=0) in the segmentation mask images, following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation).

They have used `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` for `OUTPUT_CLASSES = 3`, as shown below:

```
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 3

model = unet_model(output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 20
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 5
VALIDATION_STEPS = info.splits['test'].num_examples//BATCH_SIZE//VAL_SUBSPLITS

model_history = model.fit(train_batches, epochs=EPOCHS,
                      steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                      validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                      validation_data=test_batches,
                      callbacks=[DisplayCallback()])
```

If I use the same network with `OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2` the training loss is `NaN`.

What should I use for the loss function since I only have 2 classes unlike the example dataset ([Oxford IIIT Pets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/oxford_iiit_pet)) used here which has 3 classes.

Comment: Can you please share your feature and label tensor's shape?

Comment: feature is `128X128X3` and label is `128X128X1`